# Python's input() or raw_input() redirect to stderr instead of stdout

Tags: python, stdout

`test = input("Test: ")`

`$ python3 test.py 2> /dev/null`

I can input values but `Test:` does not show in the output. How do I specify to redirect `input()` to stdout?

Comment: Why would you expect any output? What functions do you know that allow you to generate output?

Comment: Do you simply want to print the result of `input("Test: ")`? If so, `print(test)` will work fine.

Comment: @ChristianDean Yes, that is true. But the goal was for the function argument (in this case "Test :") to show up as well, I am well aware the variable works fine.

Comment: Prompts are *supposed* to go on standard error.  Why would you want them on standard output instead?

Comment: @DavisHerring You are wrong, they are NOT according to the **official** documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Comment: @bashbin: The situation is [rather more complicated](https://bugs.python.org/issue1927) than the documentation suggests.  But I wasn’t talking about Python in particular, but *any* CLI program.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should save stdout

```
tempOut = sys.stdout
```

Then, you should redirect stdout in program

```
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
```

Next, you can read with "input"

```
data = input("Test: ")
```

In the end, you must redirect stdout to original

```
sys.stdout = tempOut
```