# Separate input prompts from return values when calling Python script inside shell command substitution

Tags: python, bash, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I have a simple Python script that asks the user for an ID and returns a serial number:

```py
...
id = input("Enter ID (0-indexed):\n")
...
print(serial_number)
```

I'm using this .py script inside of a larger bash script via command substitution:

```bash
serial_number=$(./get_serial_no.py)
echo "$serial_number"
```

The problem I'm facing is the following: since command substitution takes the entire output of the command as input, the input prompt inside the Python script is also stored in the `serial_number` variable and never gets displayed on screen (until the `echo`). Therefore, if I run the shell script, the console waits for input without giving me a prompt. Is there a way to separate the Python prompt from the value that I want returned via command substitution (i.e. the serial number)? The only things I can think of is either write the serial number to another file, or ask for input inside of the shell script and pass the ID as an option to the Python script.

Comment: Good practice software should be writing prompts to stderr, not stdout, so you shouldn't be seeing this at all if Python's `input()` call is written sanely. OTOH, having a program you run in a command substitution prompt the user in the first place is irregular; Timur's answer is on-point.

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/72258954/2125671

Comment: @Philippe This should be the accepted answer, as it directly answers my question: "Is there a way to separate the Python prompt from the value that I want returned via command substitution?". Should one of us add an answer describing this method, or is this comment enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend against prompts if you are using a python script in a shell script. Use command-line options with a library such as [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). It is so much easier, plus you get input validation as a bonus:

```
import argparse

parser.add_argument(
    '-s',
    '--serial_number',
    type = int,
    default = 12345,
    required = False,
    help = re.sub(
        r'\s+', r' ',
        
    '''Serial number (default: %(default)s)'''))
 
options = parser.parse_args()
print(optiions.serial_number)
```

Comment: This is a great approach and it's what I will implement, but I believe it'd be useful for others to see how one can redirect the prompt to stderr instead of stdout, as per @Philippe's comment under my question.